# ReactNative TextInput Focus

Tags: react-native

I'm having a form in my application where I want the user to be able to go to the next TextInput by clicking the "Next" return button.
My Input component:

```
    export default class Input extends Component {

  focusNextField = (nextField) => {
    console.log('NEXT FIELD:', nextField);
    this.refs[nextField].focus();
  }

  render() {

    var keyboardType = this.props.keyboardType || 'default';
    var style = [styles.textInput, this.props.style];

    if (this.props.hasError) style.push(styles.error);

    return (
      <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}
          style={style}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          ref={this.props.reference}
          returnKeyType= {this.props.returnType}
          onSubmitEditing={() => this.focusNextField(this.props.fieldRef)}
          secureTextEntry={this.props.isPassword}
          value={this.props.value}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent" />
        {this.props.hasError && this.props.errorMessage ? <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{this.props.errorMessage}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And how it is used:

```
<Input onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })} value={this.state.email} returnType={"next"} reference={'1'} fieldRef={'2'} keyboardType="email-address" />

      <Text style={{ color: '#fff', marginTop: 10, }}>Password</Text>
      <Input onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })} value={this.state.password} returnType={"done"}
       reference={'2'} fieldRef={'2'} isPassword={true} />
```

But I get the error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating _this.refs[nextField].focus)
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you are still trying to do this but for anyone else who has the problem, please do the following :

1. Add this code to your imports (anywhere in your imports)

   ```
   import { findNodeHandle } from 'react-native';
   import TextInputState from 'react-native/lib/TextInputState';
   export function focusTextInput(node) {
     try {
       TextInputState.focusTextInput(findNodeHandle(node));
     } catch(e) {
       console.log("Couldn't focus text input: ", e.message)
     }
   };
   ```
2. Add the following lines to your constructor

   ```
   this.focusNextField = this.focusNextField.bind(this);
   this.inputs = {};
   ```
3. Add the following function to your class

   ```
   focusNextField(id) {
     this.inputs[id].focus();
   }
   ```
4. Edit your `TextInput` as follow :

   ```
   <TextInput
     onSubmitEditing={() => {this.focusNextField('two');}}
     ref={ input => {this.inputs['one'] = input;}}
   />
   <TextInput
     onSubmitEditing={() => {this.focusNextField('three');}}
     ref={ input => {this.inputs['two'] = input;}}
   />
   ....
   ```

[Here is the source of that answer](https://medium.com/reactnative/tabbing-through-input-fields-ef283f923ab1)

Worked in 0.45 for me.